# Third Party API calling in Vespa

Tags: vespa

How to call third party API in Vespa?.Is it better to call third party API in Searcher? How will they configured? Is it mandatory to use Annonating processor and Data processor?

Comment: Actually I want that when I query from vespa then the search result will be sent to somewhere else using third party POST API. How will I call this API? Do I have to write in Searcher or somewhere else? Please please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; write a Searcher that calls the third party. Configuration will be injected if you configure like in https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/configuring-components.html